# Approval Status applied to an item upon adding to a Bundle

Tags: publishing, 2013, workflow, bundles

In Tridion 2011 an item gets an approval status on upon completion of an activity. Its the same with Bundle workflows in 2013. Bundle workflow template also gives an option to allow adding an item to a Bundle with an inflight workflow. When someone does it, the requirement I've is that the item should get published right away, as its added to the Bundle. But if the item doesn't get an approval status of that of the bundle, it won;'t get published and would complain, that the item does not meet approval status. So the custom solution I think of is to put a loop around all activities in the workflow template where a user can add/remove items. Forcefully finish the activity and start the activity and make the template messier! Is there any better option? Or because of Bundle workflows and option to add in-between should the product behavior enhance and have the approval status applied to the item as soon as its added to the Bundle! Thanks in advance for looking at this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a valid enhancement request.  Approval Statuses are not handled like Metadata here.  Their behavior is the same with a single item workflow as they are now with multi-item bundle workflow.

Comment: Hi Amit - Thanks for your input, would putting a loop around every manual step be the ideal solution? Or do we have any other ideas we can implement?

Comment: The only way to assign an approval status to an item is to have the item finish an activity that sets that status, so looping may be your best approach... Event System code could be used to start & finish the activity

Comment: Support was generous as usual to raise an enhancement :). Thanks a ton.

Comment: In my opinion adding an item to bundle which is in the middle of workflow should not result an approval status immediately being applied. Keep in mind the approval status was put on other item(s) in an earlier workflow step, and this newly added item did not go through this step. So, my suggestion, would be to restrict adding items to workflow in steps where publishing occurs, which will ensure that it does not fail. However, an earlier step should be added where the item can be added and when activity finishes the approval status will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are adding a new item to the Bundle, you can publish it using a Publication Target with no Minimal Approval Status, you will be publishing the version that was added to the Bundle (Major version, or Reserved State - The resolver should support "New Items"). I can see problems if you are adding a component that is tied to an static component template since the resolver will add the using items as well.

Comment: Thanks Eric, if we get the new items issues resolved then we can publish to a target with no minimal approval status. Correct me if my understanding is wrong here.